# How to Fire Resize event after all images resize

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, razor

I have a function that is being called on window resize

```
$(window).resize(setVideoElements);
```

That function sets the height for a class of videoThumbnail containers

```
var setVideoElements = function () { setElementsHeight('.videothumbnail'); };

function setElementsHeight(selector) {

    console.log('setting Max element height');

    // Get an array of all element heights
    var elementHeights = $(selector).map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    // Math.max takes a variable number of arguments
    // `apply` is equivalent to passing each height as an argument
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, elementHeights);

    // Set each height to the max height
    $(selector).height(maxHeight);
}
```

The function works fine except for the fact that its firing too quickly

```
<div class="thumbnail videothumbnail">
  <a href="@Url.Action("Video", new { ID = Video.ID })">
    <img class="videoThumbnailImg" src="@Video.ThumbnailUrl" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="caption">
     <h3>@Video.Name</h3>
     @foreach (var tag in Video.TagsToVideos)
     {
        <span><a href="#">@tag.Tag.Name</a></span>
     }
  <p>@Video.Description</p>
</div>
```

The issues is that the function is firing before the images are resize. I need to fire the resize function after all of the images have already been resized.

Do anyone know how to fire this function once after all of the images have Resized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<img>` HTML Element has an `onload` callback. It fires when the image data has finished downloading from its source. Utilise this to make note of when an image is loaded. Count the load events and call `setElementHeight` once all your images are loaded.

An example could look like the below:

```
var sources = ['img/a.jpg', 'img/b.jpg', 'img/c.jpg'],
    loaded = 0;

for (var idx in sources) {
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.onload = function() {
    loaded++;
    if(loaded === sources.length) {
      setElementHeight();
    }
  }
  img.src = sources[idx];
}
```

Comment: That makes sense do you know how to do it without all the event handlers?

Comment: What do you mean without the event handlers? The point is to make use of the onload event, so you need event handlers.

Comment: I just meant with out adding one for each image, they are dynamically loaded from a infinite scroll algorithm, so I'll have to bind the load to the body.  This will definetly work though i was just hoping for a way to bind to a container or something but I dont know if what i want is possible

Comment: I think I was mistaken, The Images are already loaded I just need to fire the function after the resize of the img occurs

Answer (score 1):

for anyone wondering I needed to clear the fixed height that I set on the resize

```
function clearHeight(selector) {
    $(selector).height('auto');
}
```